# Count lines in pipe stream without consume

Tags: c++11

I open a pipe stream with given `cmd` command:

```
FILE* fp = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
```

**How to count its lines without consume?**

I tried:

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
unsigned int lines = 0;

while(getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1){
    ++lines;
}
```

But it consumes `fp` pipe stream.

Comment: Is not it pure C question? You use methods which are worst practice in C++.

Comment: Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/

Comment: `FILE*` has no `peek` method, I cant use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I guess you are on Linux or some other POSIX system.</sup>

You basically cannot process the data from a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (internally used by [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) ...) *without* consuming it, since pipes are non-seekable ([lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) would fail with `ESPIPE`, [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) would fail with `EACCESS`)

You could either redirect the command to some temporary file (using lower level `fork`,`dup2`,`execve` [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), as explained in [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)) then process that file and rewind it (and/or resend it elsewhere) or read all the data from the pipe into memory (so the available memory is a limiting factor).

Comment: The fact that pipes are non-seekable is the key. Now it works like a charm. Thanks.